# Simple check for SELECT query empty result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Can anyone point out how to check if a select query returns non empty result set?

For example I have next query:

```
SELECT * FROM service s WHERE s.service_id = ?;
```

Should I do something like next:

```
ISNULL(SELECT * FROM service s WHERE s.service_id = ?)
```

to test if result set is not empty?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What will you do next after making the check?

Comment: it is not clear if you want a result set returned and then check if any rows were int it, or if you just want to check if a query returns any rows without a result set??

Comment: I want to know, if there will be any rows in a result set.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use @@ROWCOUNT:

```
SELECT * FROM service s WHERE s.service_id = ?;

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
   -- do stuff here.....
```

According to [SQL Server Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx):

> Returns the number of rows affected by
>   the last statement. If the number of
>   rows is more than 2 billion, use
>   ROWCOUNT_BIG.

Comment: This is quiet straight forward, I like it. And that's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: It is worth noting that @@ROWCOUNT is only available in Transact-SQL

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService: yes - this question **IS** about SQL Server which uses T-SQL ....

Comment: field value is NULL but @@ROWCOUNT return 1 ! Confusing :|

Comment: Of course it returns 1! If there is a row being returned it doesn't matter what the row's columns look like. A column with null value can be valuable information.

Answer (score 132):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM service s WHERE s.service_id = ?)
 BEGIN
   --DO STUFF HERE

 END
```

Comment: Change 'SELECT *' to 'SELECT TOP 1 *' for efficiency

Comment: @Ed B: It doesn't matter because EXISTS returns true on the first successful match.  Test using `EXISTS (SELECT 1/0 FROM SERVICE...` - it should return a can't divide by zero, but it won't

Comment: @Ed B & @OMG Ponies, yea, I think SQL Server is smart enough to optimize the `EXISTS (SELECT *` or `EXISTS (SELECT 1` or `EXISTS (SELECT 1/0` away

Comment: @OMG Ponies, @KM - The only reason I tell my developers to use Select 1 is to simplify searches to squash uses of Select *. In addition, I have run into efficiency problems in databases other than SQL Server (cough Access cough) where it did something with the Select clause for some silly reason.

Comment: I can note this is better than the accepted answer when you _only_ want to test if it is empty and not return a result set, such as if in a stored proc you do not want to return a result yet.

Answer (score 14):

I agree with Ed B. You should use EXISTS method but a more efficient way to do this is:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM service s WHERE s.service_id = ?)
BEGIN
   --DO STUFF HERE

END
```

HTH

Comment: If you agree, you should vote for that answer.  Rather than repost identical content...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: It's not identical. He changed the * to a 1.

Comment: Well, using "(SELECT TOP 1 * ..." would be more efficient than using "SELECT 1..."

Comment: I get identical query plans using `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` for `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ...` and  `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...`

Comment: Identical results because RDBMS optimizes suboptimal query implicitly. For my taste, this answer is cleaner and doesn't depend on optimization. Nothing is done "behind the scene" and it doesn't require knowledge about query optimizations.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it in a number of ways.

```
IF EXISTS(select * from ....)
begin
 -- select * from .... 
end
else
 -- do something
```

Or you can use `IF NOT EXISTS , @@ROW_COUNT` like

```
select * from ....
IF(@@ROW_COUNT>0)
begin
-- do something
end
```

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM service s WHERE s.service_id = ?;

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'no rows!'
END
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM service s WHERE s.service_id = ?
```

Comment: Any difference with count(*)?

Comment: @liang, yes, no actual data is read from disk so it's faster.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the below posts a bit:

If all you care about is if at least one matching row is in the DB then use `exists` as it is the most efficient way of checking this: it will return true as soon as it finds at least one matching row whereas `count`, etc will find all matching rows.

If you actually need to use the data for processing or if the query has side effects, or if you need to know the actual total number of rows then checking the `ROWCOUNT` or `count` is probably the best way on hand.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM service s WHERE s.service_id = ?;
IF @@rowcount = 0
begin
select 'no data'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM service s WHERE s.service_id = ?;
```

test if count == 0 .

More baroquely:

select case when (SELECT count(*) as count FROM service s WHERE s.service_id = ?) = 0 
   then 'No rows, bro!' else 'You got data!" end as stupid_message;

Answer (score 0):

In my sql use information function

```
select FOUND_ROWS();
```

it will return the no. of rows returned by select query.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT count(*) as CountThis ....`

Then you can compare it as string like so:

```
IF CHECKROW_RS("CountThis")="0" THEN ...
```

`CHECKROW_RS` is an object

Answer (score 0):

well there is a way to do it a little more code but really effective

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages";  //your query
$result=$connvar->query($sql);    //$connvar is the connection variable
$flag=0;
     while($rows2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
    { $flag++;}
    
if($flag==0){no rows selected;}
else{
echo $flag." "."rows are selected"
}
```