# sql - return a row of constant values if row does not exist

Tags: sql, jdbctemplate, named-parameters

I want to be able to return a row of `none, none, 0` if no row is returned from query. I have this SQL:

```
select first, last, count(address)
from employee
where last in ('james', 'smith', 'hankers')
group by first, last
union all 
select 'none', 'none', 0
from dual
where not exists (select * from employee where last in ('james', 'smith', 'hankers'));
```

From DB, an entry for `james` and `smith` exists but no entry exists for `hankers`.

But this query only returns for when an entry exists. Does not return `none, none, 0`.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: In this example, I am passing 3 hard coded values as `last`, but I would like to know a work-around if we were passing the values in as a list parameter like so `(:last)` through getJdbcTemplate.

Comment: you can use rowcount, like here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884996/simple-check-for-select-query-empty-result

Comment: Which db you used?

Comment: Okey,  I support  aguetat, but his example in msSql, But In oracle, you can select count for checking.

Answer (score 0):

The `NOT EXISTS` is applied taking into consideration *all* of the values listed. So, if *any one* value exists then the `NOT EXISTS` is not satisfied.

As a work-around you can use an in-line table with the specified values and left join your original table to it:

```
select coalesce(t2.first, 'none'), 
       coalesce(t2.last, 'none'), 
       count(t2.address)
from (
   select 'james' as last
   union all
   select 'smith'
   union all
   select 'hankers') t1
left join employee t2 ON t1.last = t2.last
group by coalesce(t2.first, 'none'), 
         coalesce(t2.last, 'none')
```

If there is no match, as is the case for `last='hankers'`, then `count(t2.address)` evaluates to `0` and thus `'none', 'none', 0` is returned.

Comment: I see. Thank you. However, I should have clarified in original post, but what would be the workaround if we didn't know the exact size of the `last` parameters? In the example, I am passing hard coded 3 values as `last`, but in my actual SQL I do not know the values and am passing a list paramater like this `in (:last);`

Comment: @qollers Another workaround would be to populate a temp table with all the values. The info about the last names has to be stored in a relational structure of some sort if you want to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you,

```
_count NUMBER(10);

select count(*) into _count
from employee
where last in ('james', 'smith', 'hankers');

if(_count > 0)
then
   select first, last, count(address) c
   from employee
   where last in ('james', 'smith', 'hankers')
   group by first, last
else
   select 'none' first, 'none' last, 0 c   from dual
end if
```

Comment: `_count NUMBER(10);` are we declaring number variable here? Sorry, am beginner at SQL

Comment: If you are using stored procedure to perform db operations, you can declare variables.