# when no data found in sybase how to handle it?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

how to handle no data found is sybase ?
in oracle i can do it like below

```
BEGIN

select into...

EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
do_something
END;
```

Comment: Can't you just use [`@@rowcount`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1601/doc/html/san1278452893271.html), [the same as SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884996/simple-check-for-select-query-empty-result)?

Comment: Assuming you mean Sybase ASE and not Sybase IQ or Sybase SQL Anywhere (you did not specify). Just check for @@rowcount = 0. But this must be done immediately after the statement, since any other statement will reset this variable.So in practice it's best to first (directly after the DML statement) copy the @@error and @@rowcount values into local variables, and then test the values of those.

Comment: Incidentally, SELECT INTO in ASE does something very different from Oracle: in ASE, it creates a new table. To assign a value to a variable, use SELECT @var = <expression> instead.